# ¿Semejanza coseno a la mano y GraphLab recommender con coseno parámetro no dan los mismos output?

Tags: python, algoritmos, matemáticas, inteligencia-artificial

Intento crear un sistema de recomendación a la mano y con la ayuda de graphlab `item_similarity_recommender`. Sin embargo, no me dan los mismos output.

#### A la mano

Aqui esta cómo luce los datos. Hay `eclipse_id`, las publicidades, con `subscriber_id`. En el centro esta cuentas tiempos el subscriber ha interactuado con una publicidad:

[image]

Hoy calculemos la matriz de similitud y publicidad recomendación para cada usario. `data_ibs` esta la matriz de similitud entre las publicidades. Esta null al principio.

```
# iteramos sobre las lineas
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
    # iteramos sobre las columnas
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
      # llenamos la matriz con coseno  semejanza
      data_ibs.iloc[i,j] = 1-cosine(data.iloc[:,i],data.iloc[:,j])

# Creamos una matriz para las publicidades similares con otras publicidades
data_neighbours = pd.DataFrame(index=data_ibs.columns,columns=range(1,11))
 
# iteremos sobre la matriz de semejanza coseno para escribir las correctas y escribir las publicidades id 
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)):
    data_neighbours.iloc[i,:10] = data_ibs.iloc[0:,i].sort_values(ascending=False)[:10].index

data_neighbours.head(6).iloc[:6,1:6]
# Hay un error : 6413 da 6413
```

[image: data_neighbour]

Utilisemos las mejoras publicidades :

```
data_recommend = pd.DataFrame(index=data_sims.index, columns=['user','1','2','3','4','5','6'])
data_recommend.iloc[0:,0] = data_sims.iloc[:,0]
```

En lugar de utilisar su puntuaciones, queremos su id :

```
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    data_recommend.iloc[i,1:] = data_sims.iloc[i,:].sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1:7,].index.transpose()
```

Y aqui esta la recomendación :

[image: recommendation sample: subscriber 13 has ad 10411 recommended for instance]

#### GraphLab recomendación

```
# Leemos users file:
products = pd.DataFrame(listado)
products['eclipse_id'] = products['eclipse_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)
sf = SFrame(data=products)
print sf
ratings_base,ratings_test = sf.random_split(.8, seed=0)
```

Aqui formamos el algoritmo

```
personalized_model = graphlab.item_similarity_recommender.create(ratings_base, user_id='subscriber_id', item_id='eclipse_id', target='count', similarity_type='cosine')
```

U aqui esta la recomendación del primer usuario :

```
personalized_model.recommend(users=[users[0]])
```

[image: graphlab recommnedation system : subscriber 13 has ad 6565 recommended]

Como lo pueden ver, hay una aguda diferencia  entre los dos sistemas.

#### Vinculo entre los sistemas :

En el modelo creado a la mano, el vinculo esta con `listado` que esta una matriz en formato JSON.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listado)
data = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

#### Conclusión y pregunta :

¿Porque coseno semejanza creado a la mano y y graphlab `item_similarity_recommender` creado con `cosine` parámetro sistema de recomendación no tengan el mismo output ? ¿Hay un error ?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que se están usando métricas diferentes, mientras el primero utiliza [la diferencia coseno de scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) definida como

> difCos(u,v)=1- u.v/(Norm[u]Norm[v])

y en el segundo caso se utiliza la similitud coseno que es

> simCos(u,v)=1 - difCos(u,v)

mientras la primera mide la diferencia, la segunda mide la similitud.